# Angular2 typescript search multiply values in array from array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, typescript

Question about searching values from array into another array. Example of arrays:

```
 items = [{"name":"Goran", "category":[0:3, 1:5]}, {"name":"Marko", "category":[0:5, 1:4]}]

 arr1 = ["5", "4", "3"]
```

Typescript try:

```
let result = items.filter(item => arr1.find(f => f == items.category))
```

and the result is none. Can you give me hint how can I do this in one line of code. Basically this is filter from template. I you can image an array of checkbox checking the values from json object. So I want to find values where from **arr1** in object **items**.

Comment: [0:3, 1:5] , it should be [3,5] only

Comment: Is `category` supposed to be an array of numbers? And if so, do you want ANY item in `arr1` to be in the `category` array? Or for them to contain the same items?

Comment: Yea category is only an array. And I want to find all numbers from arr1 in category.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output you were trying to receive?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use index of :

```
let result = items.filter(item => {
    return arr1.indexOf(items.category) > -1        
})
```